# Quick question about this integral:

Tags: integration

Is this true:$\int_0^1 1(x)_{(o,p)}dx=\int_0^p dx$ even when $p>1$? I guess I am wondering if you can use delta functions to sort of stretch integrals.

Answer (score 1):

No; by the definition of the integral, you have $0\leq x\leq1$, so if $p>1$, you just get $$\int_0^1 1(x)_{(0,p)}=\int_0^1\,dx=1.$$